# How to display JSON data as a table on node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

Hello I have been trying to figure out how to create a table with my mongo database. I was thinking of looping the data and displaying it, but I am not familiar on how to do it in node.js Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var port = 8080;
var User = require("./models/user");

var db = 'mongodb://localhost/drbeen';
mongoose.connect(db);
var connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

// Filter user data base on if they were registered under bedtime stories.


app.get("/users",function(req,res){
  console.log('getting all users');
  User.find(
      {
          "special-power":
              { $exists: true }
      }, {
          name: 1,
          email: 1,
          school: 1,
          workplace: 1,
          profession: 1,
          "special-power": 1
        })
  .exec(function (err, users){
    if(err){
      res.send('error has occured');
    } else {
      console.log(users);
      res.json(users);
  }
  });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('app listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a json file like this :

```
data = {name:'john',age:20}
```

You can call it in `jade` ([template engine](http://pugjs.org)) file like this :

```
table
 td
  each val in data
   val.name
```

Comment: better way, isn't ?